# syncdb and validate not working

Tags: django, django-models

when i try to validate my models, the following errors show up

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rdflib-4.0.1-py2.7.egg/rdflib/plugin.py:108: UserWarning: Module demo was already imported from /home/ruppesh/gitGnowsys/ishan/gstudio_15June/gnowsys-studio/demo/../demo/__init__.pyc, but /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnowsys_studio-0.5.dev-py2.7.egg is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import iter_entry_points
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 79, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/validate.py", line 9, in handle_noargs
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnowsys_studio-0.5.dev-py2.7.egg/gstudio/models.py", line 3068, in <module>
    mptt.register(Metatype, order_insertion_by=['title'])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_mptt-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/mptt/__init__.py", line 13, in register
    return MPTTModelBase.register(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_mptt-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/mptt/models.py", line 281, in register
    obj = getattr(cls, attr)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tagging-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/tagging/fields.py", line 53, in __get__
    return edit_string_for_tags(Tag.objects.usage_for_model(owner))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tagging-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/tagging/models.py", line 147, in usage_for_model
    usage = self.usage_for_queryset(queryset, counts, min_count)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tagging-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/tagging/models.py", line 181, in usage_for_queryset
    return self._get_usage(queryset.model, counts, min_count, extra_joins, extra_criteria, params)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_tagging-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/tagging/models.py", line 106, in _get_usage
    'content_type_id': ContentType.objects.get_for_model(model).pk,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 42, in get_for_model
    defaults = {'name': smart_unicode(opts.verbose_name_raw)},
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 134, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 445, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 361, in get
    num = len(clone)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 85, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 291, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 763, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 818, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 344, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: django_content_type
```

Comment: Do you have `django.contrib.contenttypes` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py?

Comment: Please specify the Django version and what commands you are exactly running.

Comment: django 1.4.5     command: python manage.py validate

Comment: Is `syncdb` also not working? Consider editing your question to add more details and clear explanation of what commands you have run and tried so far so that others find it easier to help you

Comment: syncdb is also not working. i have mentioned that in the title itself. The same errors showup on syncdb